# confusion matrix as the result of neural network in matlab

Tags: neural-network

2 questions, 1- I used neural network matlab toolbox to train a neural for classification, but each time I close the program and train and test the NN, I got different results!! do you know what happend?
2- which value in the confusion matrix would be my final accuracy of my network?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you use Matlab's neural network toolbox you have the option of choosing the percentage of your Training, Validation and Testing data (the default is 70% for training and 15-15% for validation and testing). The toolbox divides your data randomly, this is why you get different results. 
   You can set a fix training, validation and testing data set by modifying the generated simple script.
2. You need the Test Confusion Matrix

I hope it helped!